# Client Certificates

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I’m presently working on a portal for one of our clients and this is my first time dealing with security certificates and here are a few questions that I have.

I understand that a server certificate would need to be installed on the server and then a client certificate need to be installed on the client browser which would connect/interact to the server in a secure fashion. I still need to talk to our team regarding the certificates but I have a few questions that I would like to understand before moving forward.

1. Will I be provided a single server certificate that I would install on IIS
2. Will my users have to install certificate on their browser each and everytime
3. What if my client uses a public computer
4. What if my client uses an another computer ? will they need to install a certificate and will they install the same certificate that has been provided or get a new certificate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I be provided a single server certificate that I would install on IIS

The issuer will provide you  a certificate and the certification chain. You need to configure both

> Will my users have to install certificate on their browser each and everytime

User have to install the client certificate and the root certificate of the chain only once.

> What if my client uses a public computer

They have to install certificates, but then, any other user of that computer will get access to the user account. It is not recommended to install private certificate in public computers

> What if my client uses an another computer ? will they need to install a certificate and will they install the same certificate that has been provided or get a new certificate ?

User can install the certificate files in any computer or devices several times